# Get data from fire base to node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to get data from my database on fire base and want to save that data to amount  `amount: snapshot,` I did apply this `const snapshot = firestore.collection('payment').doc(context.params.amount).get();` does that works in the same way? but I am getting an error that context is undefined.
I actually want to get data from database.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const firestore= admin.firestore();
const stripe = require('stripe')('');
const snapshot = firestore.collection('payment').doc(context.params.amount).get();

const customer =  stripe.customers.create({
  email: 'customer@example1.com',
});
stripe.customers
  .create({
    email: 'foo-customer@example.com',
  })
  .then((customer) => {
    return stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, {
      source: 'tok_visa',
    });
  })
  .then((source) => {
    return stripe.charges.create({
      amount: snapshot,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: source.customer,
    });
  })
  .then((charge) => {
    // New charge created on a new customer
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Deal with an error
  });
```

Comment: It appears you're trying to use Cloud Functions, but I don't even see a function entry point here.  Without that, the code will never deploy or run.

Comment: I am unable to make cloud functions can you guide me  how can I convert this given code to cloud functions where value get from fire base from collection payment and document amount.

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation, sample code, codelabs provided by Firebase.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson I am very new with node.js so hope your instruction will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to get `amount` through accessing `params` through context,
depends on your error, this means `context` is `undefined` which means you are trying to get `params` of `undefined`. you need to explain what is `context` means here, is it a global variable? is this code inside a `cloud function`? if `yes` you need to move this declaration `const snapshot = firestore.collection('payment').doc(context.params.amount).get();`
  inside your cloud function ,
this is an [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) of firebase cloud function

Comment: I am unable to make cloud functions can you guide me how can I convert this given code to cloud functions where value get from fire base from collection payment and document amount.